# How to correctly display plotly density_mapbox?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, heatmap, density-plot

I am starting to learn about plotly color scales.
I have this code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'firefox'


fig = px.density_mapbox(df_chestie_psq_2018, lat='Lat', lon='Long', z='Psq', radius=30,
                                                        center=go.layout.mapbox.Center (
                                   lat=44.439663,
                                   lon=26.096306
                                ), zoom=10, color_continuous_scale= [
                [0.0, "green"],
                [0.5, "green"],
                [0.51111111, "yellow"],
                [0.71111111, "yellow"],
                [0.71111112, "red"],
                [1, "red"]],
                        opacity = 0.5
                        )
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="dark", mapbox_accesstoken='some_token')
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(b=0, t=0, l=0, r=0))
fig.show()
```

Where df_chestie_psq_2018 is a dataframe and I want to distinguish the values in that dataframe by Psq. The proble is that it displays the following map:

[image]

The problem is that green should be the dominant color and as you can see, it displays the red color. Also, if I zoom in, the color disappear. I just want to see the green value between some values , yellow at other values and red at what is left. But I can manage to do it successfully.

An easy example with the same problem that is easy to reproduce:

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.carshare()


fig = px.density_mapbox(df, lat='centroid_lat', lon='centroid_lon', z='car_hours', radius=30,
             color_continuous_scale= [
                [0.0, "green"],
                [0.5, "green"],
                [0.51111111, "yellow"],
                [0.71111111, "yellow"],
                [0.71111112, "red"],
                [1, "red"]],
                        opacity = 0.5
                        )


fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter")
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(b=0, t=0, l=0, r=0))

fig.show()
```

I just want to see green color, red color and yellow color based on car_hours value.

Comment: Hi Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? In particular, in order to reproduce it, we will need you to share the data.

Comment: Edit: I added code that can be reproduced

Answer (score 3):

You should use scatter_mapbox instead

```
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.express as px
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.carshare()


fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat='centroid_lat', lon='centroid_lon', color='car_hours',
             color_continuous_scale= [
                [0.0, "green"],
                [0.5, "green"],
                [0.51111111, "yellow"],
                [0.71111111, "yellow"],
                [0.71111112, "red"],
                [1, "red"]],
                        opacity = 0.5
                        )


fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-darkmatter")
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(b=0, t=0, l=0, r=0))

fig.show()
```

[image]